# Is there any method to expand makefile to a new makefile

Tags: makefile, expand

makefile variable and function are unreadable to human if some project is written to be very abstractive,first step of running makefile is expand all the variable and function.I want save this step to a new makefile and then to understand the makefile is easily.

Comment: Do you know about `make -d`? There's a lot of debugging information available there.

Comment: I think the poster is looking for `make -p`, not `make -d`.  However, even this is probably not going to allow "understanding the makefile easily".  But, that's all we have available.

Comment: One might explore [`kati`](https://github.com/google/kati), a Google `make` reimplementation that generates a quite simple (but LONG) Ninja files.